# Replacing The Tab Character In A String

Tags: python, replace, count, tabs, character

Let's say I have a string like this: 
`a = a = "\t\t\t\t"` 
If I print out the count of `"\t"` in the string, this is the output: 
`print(a.count("\t"))    ==      output = 4` \
If I wanted to replace `"\t"` at any given occurrence in that string, how would I do it? 
ex: 
`a.replace("\t", "a") #replacing the (first occurrence?) of "\t?` 
`print(a.count("\t"))    ==      output = 3`

**However**, the `"\t"` is not getting replaced by `"a"` and therefore the `"\t"` count is still 4. Is there a way I can do this; preferably replace any given occurrence of `"\t"` within the string?

Comment: Be aware that "replace" returns a new, modified string and doesn't change the original string.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions. It is another way to replace all the occurencies by specific pattern

Answer (score 0):

As Michael Butscher says, `str.replace()` returns a new string with replacements done. By default, all occurrences are replaced. Tabs are not a special case. This should do it:

```
a = a.replace("\t", "a")
print(a.count("\t"))
```

See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20replace#str.replace

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the responses as they really opened the door to the solution. What I have done is converted a into a list:

```
a = "\t\t\t\t" 
b = a.list() 

#print(b): 
#['\t', '\t', '\t', '\t']
```

I can then just use indices to replace what I need `b[0] = "a"`, and then just convert it back into a str when I am done. This suits my purpose, but there are multiple ways of dealing with it like if I wanted to change all the `"\t"` into a "a" I could do a simple iteration like this:

```
for x in range(0, len(b)): 
    if b[x] == "\t": 
        b[x] = "a"
```

Of course the `replace()` function could do the same with it in string format, but at least with this iteration I could add more conditional logic if needed.